Simple insert times out in application, but fast in SSMS
In my application I have a simple insert, when captured with profiler it looks like this
insert into ford.tblFordCompoundFlowVehicle
  (FordCompoundFlowID, CompoundVehicleID, SortOrder, Status1ToSend, Status2ToSend, FordFlowTriggerID, SendTriggerSatisfied, DateSend, FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID)
select fcfd.FordCompoundFlowID, 
       9711, 
       fcfdd.SortOrder, 
       fcfdd.Status1ToSend, 
       fcfdd.Status2ToSend, 
       fcfdd.FordFlowTriggerID, 
       0, 
       null,
       2
from   ford.tblFordCompoundFlowDefinitionDetail fcfdd
  inner join ford.tblFordCompoundFlowDefinition fcfd on fcfdd.FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID = fcfd.FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID 
where  fcfdd.FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID = 2
order by fcfdd.SortOrder

This is sent to the database using Dapper like this
 string sql =
     $"""
     insert into ford.tblFordCompoundFlowVehicle
       (FordCompoundFlowID, CompoundVehicleID, SortOrder, Status1ToSend, Status2ToSend, FordFlowTriggerID, SendTriggerSatisfied, DateSend, FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID)
     select fcfd.FordCompoundFlowID, 
            {compoundVehicleID}, 
            fcfdd.SortOrder, 
            fcfdd.Status1ToSend, 
            fcfdd.Status2ToSend, 
            fcfdd.FordFlowTriggerID, 
            0, 
            null,
            {fordCompoundFlowDefinitionID}
     from   ford.tblFordCompoundFlowDefinitionDetail fcfdd
       inner join ford.tblFordCompoundFlowDefinition fcfd on fcfdd.FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID = fcfd.FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID 
     where  fcfdd.FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID = {fordCompoundFlowDefinitionID.Value}
     order by fcfdd.SortOrder 
     OPTION(RECOMPILE)
     """;

 connection.Execute(sql, null, transaction);

I did not use an SqlCommand to keep this code a bit shorter, also the values are all int so SQL injection would be difficult anyway.
Now for the problem, when this query runs it takes so long it times out, but when I capture the query in profiler and run it in SSMS it is very fast.
I also tried the option OPTION(RECOMPILE) in the application, but it does not help
Execution Plans:
So I got the execution plan from SSMS
and captured the slow application plan from Activity monitor
I do not have the knowledge myself to compare these plans and see the problem, so I am hoping someone here can compare them and help me point out the problem.
The transaction is done like this
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
 {
     connection.Open();

     using (SqlTransaction transaction =  connection.BeginTransaction())
     {
         try
         {
             fordCompoundFlowDefinitionID = CreateFordCompoundFlowVehicle(connection, transaction, compoundVehicleID);
             transaction.Commit();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         { 
             transaction.Rollback();
             throw;
         }
     }
 }

private int? CreateFordCompoundFlowVehicle(SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, int compoundVehicleID)
{
    int? result = null;

    // check if there is any importdata for this compoundvehicleid, if not than it stops right here
    int? fordCompoundFlowDefinitionID = GetFordCompoundFlowDefinitionID(connection, transaction, compoundVehicleID);

    if (fordCompoundFlowDefinitionID.HasValue)
    {
        string sql =
            $"""
            insert into ford.tblFordCompoundFlowVehicle
              (FordCompoundFlowID, CompoundVehicleID, SortOrder, Status1ToSend, Status2ToSend, FordFlowTriggerID, SendTriggerSatisfied, DateSend, FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID)
            select fcfd.FordCompoundFlowID, 
                   {compoundVehicleID}, 
                   fcfdd.SortOrder, 
                   fcfdd.Status1ToSend, 
                   fcfdd.Status2ToSend, 
                   fcfdd.FordFlowTriggerID, 
                   0, 
                   null,
                   {fordCompoundFlowDefinitionID}
            from   ford.tblFordCompoundFlowDefinitionDetail fcfdd
              inner join ford.tblFordCompoundFlowDefinition fcfd on fcfdd.FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID = fcfd.FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID 
            where  fcfdd.FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID = {fordCompoundFlowDefinitionID.Value}
            order by fcfdd.SortOrder 
            OPTION(RECOMPILE)
            """;

        -- THIS TIMES OUT
        connection.Execute(sql, null, transaction);

        result = fordCompoundFlowDefinitionID;
    }

    return result;
}

I altered the code to a parametrized query as suggested, but get the same result
                string sql =
                    """
                    insert into ford.tblFordCompoundFlowVehicle
                      (FordCompoundFlowID, CompoundVehicleID, SortOrder, Status1ToSend, Status2ToSend, FordFlowTriggerID, SendTriggerSatisfied, DateSend, FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID)
                    select fcfd.FordCompoundFlowID, 
                           @CompoundVehicleID, 
                           fcfdd.SortOrder, 
                           fcfdd.Status1ToSend, 
                           fcfdd.Status2ToSend, 
                           fcfdd.FordFlowTriggerID, 
                           0, 
                           null,
                           @FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID
                    from   ford.tblFordCompoundFlowDefinitionDetail fcfdd
                      inner join ford.tblFordCompoundFlowDefinition fcfd on fcfdd.FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID = fcfd.FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID 
                    where  fcfdd.FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID = @FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID
                    order by fcfdd.SortOrder 
                    OPTION(RECOMPILE)
                    """;

                var parameters = new {CompoundVehicleID = compoundVehicleID, FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID = fordCompoundFlowDefinitionID };

                connection.Execute(sql, parameters, transaction);


The captured statement in profiler
exec sp_executesql N'insert into ford.tblFordCompoundFlowVehicle
  (FordCompoundFlowID, CompoundVehicleID, SortOrder, Status1ToSend, Status2ToSend, FordFlowTriggerID, SendTriggerSatisfied, DateSend, FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID)
select fcfd.FordCompoundFlowID, 
       @CompoundVehicleID, 
       fcfdd.SortOrder, 
       fcfdd.Status1ToSend, 
       fcfdd.Status2ToSend, 
       fcfdd.FordFlowTriggerID, 
       0, 
       null,
       @FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID
from   ford.tblFordCompoundFlowDefinitionDetail fcfdd
  inner join ford.tblFordCompoundFlowDefinition fcfd on fcfdd.FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID = fcfd.FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID 
where  fcfdd.FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID = @FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID
order by fcfdd.SortOrder 
OPTION(RECOMPILE)',N'@CompoundVehicleID int,@FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID int',@CompoundVehicleID=9711,@FordCompoundFlowDefinitionID=2
go


System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException   HResult=0x80131904
Message=Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to
completion of the operation or the server is not responding. Operation
cancelled by user.   Source=Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider
StackTrace:    at
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)    at
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)    at
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
ds)    at
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream,
TaskCompletionSource1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, String method)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource1
completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite,
String methodName)    at
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()    at
Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteCommand(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition&
command, Action2 paramReader) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 2965    at Dapper.SqlMapper.ExecuteImpl(IDbConnection cnn, CommandDefinition& command) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 656    at Dapper.SqlMapper.Execute(IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Nullable1 commandTimeout, Nullable1 commandType) in /_/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs:line 527    at WebServiceMobile.Repositories.Compound.RepositoryFordFlow.CreateFordCompoundFlowVehicle(SqlConnection connection, SqlTransaction transaction, Int32 compoundVehicleID) in C:\Development\Git\WebServices\WebServiceMobile\Repositories\Compound\Ford\RepositoryFordFlow.cs:line 124    at WebServiceMobile.Repositories.Compound.RepositoryFordFlow.HandleIncomingVehicle(Int32 compoundVehicleID, Nullable1 dateInActual) in
C:\Development\Git\WebServices\WebServiceMobile\Repositories\Compound\Ford\RepositoryFordFlow.cs:line
29
Inner Exception 1: Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out.

I tried without using a transaction, same result

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Timeout expired.  The timeout
period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is
not responding. Operation cancelled by user.'

New plan captured from the query running  in the application
plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1vTWaMIR
live statistics:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1-8MpGUA
Running sp_who2
As suggested I ran exec sp_who2 while the slow query is running, this is the result



SPID
Status
Login
HostName
BlkBy
DBName
Command
CPUTime
DiskIO
LastBatch
ProgramName
SPID
REQUESTID




87
SUSPENDED
PalmTest
XXXX
77
xxxx
INSERT
0
2
06/21 11:46:38
gttWebService
87
0




How you defined the transaction and do you commit it?

@sa-es-ir I edited the question and included that information

"I did not use an SqlCommand to keep this code a bit shorter, also the values are all int so sql injection would be difficult anyway..." - This still means you're going to run into problems with forced-parameterization.

@Dai I will put the SqlCommand back as soon as the time-out is fixed, please let's focus on the real problem

obligatory: https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

@sa-es-ir I don't make it to the commit, because of the time-out. That is why a added both execution plans so you can help me find out why I get the time out

@MitchWheat Yes I have been reading here, but it comes down to studying the execution plans which is something I don't have enough knowledge of

@GuidoG My point is relevant because forced-parameterization can cause incorrect query plan selection which in-turn leads to slow query/statement execution times.

@Dai OK, when you compare both plans can you see that this has happened then ? I can't make heads or tails of the plans

Can you share the exception as well? Is it a query or connection time out? also if possible try to check SQL Profiler as well to see what exactly app tries to run against SQL server.

@sa-es-ir I already show in the question exact what I captured from the profiler

@sa-es-ir The exact error message is included now

@Dai I parametrized the query (see edit in the question), but still the same result

@GuidoG Yes sorry I just read it again. I think the issue is not about the query plan, it should be about the transaction,  and maybe the table is locked, can you also check the exception message on SQL profiler: https://nimblegecko.com/how-to-trace-sql-server-database-errors-and-exceptions-with-sql-profiler/

@sa-es-ir I don't use the profiler from ssms but express profiler, I don't see any exception there

@sa-es-ir If the table is locked should that not be visible in the plans ?

@sa-es-ir I t ried without transaction, same result

Both pasted plans have SET ARITHABORT ON in effect which suggests that they were both generated from executing the queries in SSMS. What does the "bad" plan from Dapper look like? i.e.: it will almost certainly have a different set of @@OPTIONS in effect which could be what's affecting plan generation, execution and behaviour.

@AlwaysLearning I am sorry, but the slow plan I got from the Activity Monitor in SSMS, recent slow querys, right mouse show plan and then saved it. So it should be the plan from the application or am I missing something here ?

Quick and dirty fix for this kind of problems: update statistics (with fullscan) for some underlying table (this updates stats AND kills cached plans), run application query immediately after - this often (but not always) creates and stores better query plan. Note - do not use with(recompile) then.

As a quick test you could try prepending your queries with SET ARITHABORT OFF; before executing them in SSMS to see if they come up slow. Turning on "Display Actual Execution Plan" in the toolbar should reveal the differences.

@AlwaysLearning I am trying to capture the plan again from running in the application, give me a minute

@AlwaysLearning OK I captured the paramitrized query plan when running from the application again, see the latest edit in the question, I put the plan and the live statistics there, hopefully this helps you or someone else to help me

@AlwaysLearning With SET ARITHABORT OFF in ssms it still remains fast  there

@GuidoG while the query is running, can you run the EXEC sp_who2 and check the status and blkBy columns?

@Arvo I tried that, but still the same result

@sa-es-ir OK I did that, I put the result in the latest edit on the question

@GuidoG Now makes sense! you need to check the Blk By which shows the other SPID blocks the query and try to find that query on the same table.

@sa-es-ir Yes, finally we are making some progress here, thank you so much for showing this to me

@GuidoG Looking forward to see the actual issue:)

@sa-es-ir I posted an answer that explains what happend, what I did wrong

I have found the problem, it seems when run from the application there was a lock that puts my query in suspended state.
I discovered this thanks to a comment of @sa-es-ir that made me run sp_who2 while the slow query was running. Then I noticed a block from the same application I was running my query from, but with another spid.
So the query had actually not much to do with the problem and the execution plans should be quit similar I guess, but since the query kept waiting the client got tired of waiting and called a timeout.
How did this occur?
It seems that when your connection in C# begins a transaction, and you create a new connection that begins a new transaction, then any query that needs a row that was inserted/updated in the first transaction needs to wait until that transaction ended.
Basically I had something like this
 using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
 {
     connection.Open();

     using (SqlTransaction transaction =  connection.BeginTransaction())
     {
         try
         {
             SomeProcedure();
             transaction.Commit();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         { 
             transaction.Rollback();
             throw;
         }
     }
 }

public void SomeProcedure()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
     {
         connection.Open();

         using (SqlTransaction transaction =  connection.BeginTransaction())
         {
             try
             {
                 // HERE WAS MY QUERY THAT TIMED OUT
                 transaction.Commit();
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             { 
                 transaction.Rollback();
                 throw;
             }
         }
     }

}

I now altered my method so it checks if it is in an existing connection/transaction and then uses that and only create a new one if that is not the case.
